# How to get stacktraces with stack and GHCI?

Tags: haskell, ghci, haskell-stack

With

```
stack ghci --profile --ghci-options '+RTS -xc -RTS'
```

I get:

```
ghc: the flag -xc requires the program to be built with -prof
```

Which program is not built with `-prof` and why?

Comment: I would guess the program not being built with profiling is ghc. If you want to profile your program, you need to pass `-xc` to your program, not to ghci.

Comment: I see. Is it possible to have `xc` flag enabled for interpreted code and the libraries it runs?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to profile interpreted code.

Answer (score 0):

```
stack ghci --profile app --ghci-options "-fexternal-interpreter -prof"
```

The above seems to work for me (does take a few seconds to start). I had to add the following to my `stack.yaml`:

```
build:
  library-profiling: true
  executable-profiling: true
```

More informotation: 
https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/doc/GUIDE.md#debugging
http://simonmar.github.io/posts/2016-02-12-Stack-traces-in-GHCi.html

I may have actually run some additional commands, possibly `stack build --enable-library-profiling`.